# Ajax jquery no pasa por funcion success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo una peticion ajax a un archivo php pero por algun motivo no pasa por la funcion success y no me sale error. podrian ver cual es el problema, la ruta del archivo esta bien y no se que mas puede ser

//jquery

```
$("#lst_categoria").change(function(){
// lst_curso($(this).val());
alert("duhhhhbhubh");
 var parametros =
    {
     "operacion":"curso_unico",
     "id_cat" : $(this).val(),

    }
   $.ajax({

        data: parametros,
        url: 'prueba.php',
        type: 'POST',

        succes: function (response){
            alert("pase por aqui");
            alert(response);
            $("#lst_curso").html(response);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
         }
    });
});
```

// archivo prueba.php

```
<?php 


echo "algo";
 ?>
```

Comment: Dada la respuesta, (faltaba una "s") he votado para cerrar esta pregunta por *no relacionado debido a un fallo ortografico*

Answer (score 3):

ya encontre el error la funcion success estaba mal escrita me faltaba una s